# How to pass undefined number of inputs to a form spring mvc

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, input

I'm creating an form which will contain a sort number of hidden inputs and I would like to pass it to my spring MVC server.
The form created will be something like that (not always I will have 3 input types.. I can have more or less than it, the user will set up this value):

```
    <form id="submitCoordenadas" method="post" action="adicionaCorredores">
    <button type="submit" id="saveCoordenadas" class="btn" value="Save">Enviar</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="corredor" id="linha1" val="[Linha] Inicio: [1;1] Fim: [104;114]">
    <input type="hidden" name="corredor" id="linha2" val="[Linha] Inicio: [113;1] Fim: [1;144]">
    <input type="hidden" name="corredor" id="linha3" val="[Linha] Inicio: [113;1] Fim: [1;144]">
</form>
```

What I have tried so far is to create an object which has an List of Strings:

```
public class Corredores {

    List<String> corredor;

........ (getters and setters)
}
```

and my Spring MVC server:

```
@RequestMapping("adicionaCorredores")
    public String adicionaCorredores(Corredores valores) {
        System.out.println("Valores: " + valores.getCorredor().get(0));
        return "";
    }
```

I'm not receiving anything on "valores" parameter.

How can I do it? How can I have an undetermined number of inputs in a form and receive it in my Spring MVC server?

Comment: It will be better that if you can post the request data? You can use firebug to check what the data is. And I do think if you want to receive the data that the field corredor should be a Map and also you should use @ModelAttribute to bind the data to valores.

Comment: there is nothing in data.. could you post an answer with what can be done?

Comment: I mean the data that you send to server, not what you get from the request. we need to know what is the data format then I can figure out which type that you can use and how to use it.

Comment: I guess it is an String.But when I receive an String as parameter, I don't receive anything either

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem.. 
First of all, I was committing a mistake in my form. Instead of inserting the attribute "value" to it, I was using "val". Now my form looks like this:

```
<form id="submitCoordenadas" method="post" action="adicionaCorredores">
    <button type="submit" id="saveCoordenadas" class="btn" value="Save">Enviar</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="corredor" id="linha1" val="[Linha] Inicio: [1;1] Fim: [104;114]">
    <input type="hidden" name="corredor" id="linha2" val="[Linha] Inicio: [113;1] Fim: [1;144]">
    <input type="hidden" name="corredor" id="linha3" val="[Linha] Inicio: [113;1] Fim: [1;144]">
</form>
```

Another thing I've done is change my controller to this:

```
@RequestMapping("adicionaCorredores")
    public String adicionaCorredores(@RequestParam("corredor") String[] corredor) {

        for(int i=0; i < corredor.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Valores: " + corredor[i]);
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Instead of receiving an Object "Corredores", I'm just receiving an String array. Note that the name of this String array should be the same of the name given in the form

Hope it helps someone else!